# Using an ellipsis for the middle dimensions of a PyTorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose I have a `torch.Tensor t` of shape `(8, 3, 32, 32)`. I want to index along the first and last 2 dimensions only.

In my usecase, `t` is a batch of 8 images, of which I want to modify a patch. Suppose the patch is given by indices `idx_last = torch.tensor([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])`.
I also have `idx1 = torch.arange(4)` : I want the patch for the first 4 images.

The following does not work:

`t[idx1, ..., idx_last]`

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: It should work. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I have shape broadcasting issues. In the previous example, I managed to make it work by doing the following:
```idx = tuple((x for x in idx_last.T))``` then ```t[(idx1, ...) + idx] ```

Comment: For some reason `t[(idx1, ...) + tuple(idx_last.T)]` doesn't have the same shape as `t[idx1,..., idx_last.T]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one workaround, although it may not be the most efficient.
In the case where `idx1` is 1-dimensional (datapoint selection), and `idx_last` is multidimensional, the following gets the wanted result:

```
t[(idx1, ...) + tuple(idx_last.T)]
```

Better solutions are definitely welcome.